# Send SMS Freeswitch via web interface

Tags: freeswitch

I installed the freeswitch and bought a Khomp device to send SMS trought it! I'm able to send sms with the command line inside the freeswitch client(fs_cli). I enabled the XML-RPC module to send it via web, but I'm not able to start an application to send it via web.

Anybody had already heard about sending sms using the xml-rpc connecting to the freeswitch virtual machine and sending it?

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english.